# templatetags imported in runserver but not on wsgi

Tags: django, wsgi, django-templates, django-template-filters

im using django 1.2 and I am trying to deploy django using apache mod_wsgi.
My app works fine using the development server, but when I try to use the wsgi, it can not load file containing template filters.

I have it in structure like /app/subapp/templatetags/core_filters.py, **init**.py is located where it is supposed to. When I try to open any view loading the code, or template loading {% load core_filters %} exception occurs. It says it is not a valid tag library, at lists all the apps it tried to find core_filters in, but my app.core.templatetags.core_filters is not among them although it is listed in installed apps.

Any suggestions, sollutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error on the python path. uWsgi had different python path that contained another package with the same name

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you accidentally left your local_settings.py file on the live server, causing some pathing issues or there's some other difference between your settings.py and local_settings.py files?

Comment: no, there is no local_settings. The only difference between this project and other projects is that i do have the structure app.subapp, unlike other apps, where I do have only subapps directly.